# Multiple pasting formula for excel

Tags: excel, vba, pasting

I'd like to know if it is possible to create a macro that is gonna paste every cell from copied range multiple times (x) in one column.

Eg. we have data in form like this
a
b
c
...
And we need (eg. x=4)
a
a
a
a
b
b
b
b
c
c
c
c

Comment: The answer to your question is: "yes, it is possible".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951415/save-range-to-variable

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one:

```
Sub pCreateMultipleTimes()

    Dim strText             As String
    Dim strOutput           As String
    Dim intMultiplier       As Integer
    Dim varTempData         As Variant
    Dim lngLoop1            As Long
    Dim lngLoop2            As Long

    'Considering data to be in form so it will be in text
    strText = "a b c"

    ' x=4
    intMultiplier = 4

    'Split Text with space as delimiter and assign it to Variant
    varTempData = Split(strText, " ")

    'Loop through to create the final combination output
    For lngLoop1 = LBound(varTempData) To UBound(varTempData)
        For lngLoop2 = 1 To intMultiplier
            strOutput = Trim(strOutput & " " & varTempData(lngLoop1))
        Next lngLoop2
    Next lngLoop1
    MsgBox "Your needed Output is: " & strOutput, vbOKOnly + vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: please bear in mind that poor questions that lack any effort and/or attempt at solving are not to be answered.

Comment: @vba4all: Thank you for the reminder. Sometimes I tend to forget - Jur Pertin

Comment: Could you please advise me how to adjust the macro to data in less specific form - as it suppose to work on columns with 200+ cells of data.

Comment: And It would be much easier if it would just paste result into different column/worksheet

Comment: @MateuszKopeć, Jur has given you a good framework. Now is your opportunity to understand the code, and try to expand it to what you require.