# VBA, Why does pasting my array only paste one cell

Tags: excel, vba

I get all my values into an array and I want to paste it over to another workbook.
How come this isnt working? It is only pasting the cell A2 of destination workbook. Do I have to select the full range to paste it?

According to the answer here, the answer just pastes to one cell.
[Save range to variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951415/save-range-to-variable)

```
Dim src As Variant
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Open CM comm file
Set MainDataCM = Workbooks.Open(Sheets("Input").Range("B3") & Sheets("Input").Range("B6"))

'Copy main data tab to EPM file workbook
With Sheets("Main Data")
lastrow = Sheets("Main Data").Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
src = Sheets("Main Data").Range("A2:P" & lastrow).Value
End With
MainDataCM.Close SaveChanges:=False

'Paste into active workbook
Set MainDataCIB = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Range("B3") & Sheets("Input").Range("B9"))
With Sheets("Main Data")
lastrow = Sheets("Main Data").Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("Main Data").Range("A2:P" & lastrow).ClearContents
MainDataCIB.Sheets("Main Data").Range("A2").Value = src
End With
```

Comment: Try `MainDataCIB.Sheets("Main Data").Range("A2:P"&lastrow).Value = src`

Comment: ^^^^^^^ assigning the values from an array is not like pasting.  One needs to tell vba the size of the range into which one wants to assign the value.

Comment: That linked answer is wrong, and has been edited.

Comment: I cant do last row in the destination workbook, as the last row between source and destination will be different. So using last row too clear the range is fine, but pasting only to that may not transfer everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to output your array to a range, you need to give it the correct dimensions to output. The best way I find to do this is using the `.Resize` property of the specified range. See code below.

```vb
MainDataCIB.Sheets("Main Data").Range("A2").Resize(UBound(src,1), UBound(src,2)).Value = src
```

This approach will ensure that you are giving accurate dimensions to your output.

Comment: Thanks, does this take into account a dynamic paste range?

Comment: @excelguy as it is currently it will adjust to the dimensions of the array (using `UBound` function. You can read more about the UBound function here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ubound-function. If you do not want to use the `UBound` function to give the specifications for your ourput then you can use any `Long` type variable as arguments in the `Resize` property. But based on your question the `UBound` approach is what you're after.